# Disable Url Encoding on Asp.Net HyperLink Control in Header tag

Tags: asp.net, seo, canonical-link

I am attempting to dynamically add a  element to the html head tag in ASP.Net.

Here is my code in the master page:

```
    public string LinkConincal
    {
        get
        {
            return Canonical.Href;
        }
        set
        {
            Canonical.Attributes["href"] = value;
        }
    }
```

I use this master page property on each page and set the value to the appropriate link.

My problem is if there is a & character in the url it is being encoded (&=>&) and the link becomes invalid.

To see an example of this, on my page [www.kwyps.com/topic.aspx?t=11&p=1](http://www.kwyps.com/topic.aspx?t=11&p=1)

it is being displayed as

```
<link id="Canonical" rel="canonical" href="http://www.kwyps.com/topic.aspx?t=11&amp;p=1" />
```

instead of what I want:

```
<link id="Canonical" rel="canonical" href="http://www.kwyps.com/topic.aspx?t=11&p=1" />
```

---

**How do I disable the Url Encoding? Or is this valid? I'm trying to do this for SEO purposes.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not urlencoding its HTML/XML-encoding and is probably both valid, depending what kind of html standard you define.

If you want to force your output you can use `<%=YourCanonical%>` in the aspx/whatever and then set it in the code via  `public string YourCanonical = "http:/..."`

Comment: This works! But one problem : I couldn't specify the Property in the master page. I guess the inline statements don't work in the master page? Not a big deal. I'm fine with this solution! Thanks!

Comment: @Scen It does work in master page, but you will need to define it in the master page code.

Comment: Nope, dunno what happened there.. sorry about that! (and Thanks!)